# How can I show a help text for models/databases in admin interface?

Tags: django, django-admin

In the Django admin interface (Home -> Database -> Database administration) I'd like to show an additional help text as column in the list of databases/models (Database). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can define `form` and assign this form to `admin` class

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].help_text = 'My help text'

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ()

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

Comment: I don't want to extend the model form but the admin interface visualization. This should be possible with `models.AdminModel` I guess?

Comment: I'd use list display if I would like to change the list view output. But I would like to show a help text for the database model itselfs (e.g. corresponding to the model docstring) on the database overview site.